# Glassfish 4 domain.xml configuration

Tags: configuration, glassfish

I'm using an embedded Glassfish 4 with Arquillian for integration tests. Until now I did not need a custom domain.xml. But now I have the need to add options for the jvm to increase memory. I could find a tag named jvm-options which is probably the right thing to use. But generally speaking: Is there a reference for all the available options of the domain.xml in glassfish? The administration guide says, it is a representation of the domain model which will probably be classes.

I want to be able to find out what an existing option in the domain.xml means and also find out what an option given in the domain model maps to in xml.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to migrate from Glassfish 2 to 4, I found that Glassfish 3 documentation for domain.xml is still valid: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1753/6nmnef736/index.html